# Migration to add enum column in rails3 and enumerated_attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, enums

I need a migration to add column of type enum in rails 3. I will be using enumerated_attribute gem.

I generated a migration to add the column:

```
rails generate migration addUsage_reports_accessToClientParam usage_reports_access:enum
```

Now I need to set up the values for the enum and set the default value. Here is the generated migration:

```
class AddUsageReportsAccessToClientParam < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :client_params, :usage_reports_access, :enum
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :client_params, :usage_reports_access
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: you can set the default value like add_column :client_params, :usage_reports_access, :enum, :default => true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. This works:

```
add_column :client_params, :usage_reports_access, "ENUM('value1','value2', 'value3') DEFAULT 'value1'"
```